# App crashes when loading pre-defined list of Goal objects with associated Challenges in SwiftData and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am working with SwiftData and SwiftUI to represent a *Goal* model which has a relationship to a *Challenge* model. My goal is to preload a list of *Goals*, each with its own set of associated *Challenges*. However, when attempting to load this pre-defined list in a SwiftUI view, the app crashes.

Here are the model definitions for clarity:
**Goal Model**

```
@Model
class Goal {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var completionDate: Date
    var goalDescription: String
    var symbolName: String
    var status: Status
    var inspirationImage: Data?
    var creationDate: Date
    var feedback: [String]

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Challenge.goal) var challenges: [Challenge]?
    ...
}
```

**Challenge Model**

```
@Model
class Challenge {
    var title: String
    var challengeDescription: String

    // Relationship
    var goal: Goal?
}
```

I've created a static pre-defined list as follows:

```
static var examples: [Goal] {
    let challenge1 = Challenge(title: "Daily Meditation", challengeDescription: "Dedicate at least 10 minutes a day to meditation or mindfulness.")
    let challenge2 = Challenge(title: "Digital Detox", challengeDescription: "Reduce screen time, especially before bedtime.")
    let goal = Goal(title: "Improve Mental Health", completionDate: Date.now, goalDescription: "A commitment to nurturing one's mind, reducing stress, and fostering a positive mental environment", symbolName: "brain.head.profile", status: .ongoing, challenges: [challenge1, challenge2])
    let goals = [goal]
    return goals
}
```

In my SwiftUI view, I am attempting to load and display this pre-defined *examples* list using a *ForEach* loop.

However, when I launch the app and navigate to this view, the app crashes with an error message related to the *@Relationship* attribute of the *Goal* model.
The breakpoint is triggered at the line **return self.getValue(forKey: \.challenges)**:

```
// Error location
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Challenge.goal) var challenges: [Challenge]?
{
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _challenges)
        init(initialValue) {
                    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.challenges, to: initialValue)
                    _challenges = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    get {
                    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.challenges)
                    return self.getValue(forKey: \.challenges)
        }

    set {
                    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.challenges) {
                            self.setValue(forKey: \.challenges, to: newValue)
                    }
        }
}
```

Specifically, the error is:
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1a8a0803c)

Interestingly, if I omit the *challenges* from the *goal* instantiation, everything works perfectly.

How can I correctly load a pre-defined list of *Goal* objects with their associated *Challenges* in SwiftUI without causing the app to crash?

Comment: Try setting the relationship property after the init instead. Either `goal.challenges = [challenge1, challenge2]` or the other way around `challenge1.goal = goal`

Comment: Adding `goal.challenges = [challenge1]` doesn't make a difference. When I add `challenge1.goal = goal`, the app doesn't crash, but no challenge is added to the goal. Combining them causes the app to crash on startup.

Comment: Maybe also try to insert them into your model context before connecting them. Unfortunately this is a part of SwiftData that is quite buggy currently.

Comment: You haven't shown the code for the complete models, the setup of SwiftData, nor the code where you "preloading" goal entities, nor any code for the views. Please provide a minimal working example, optionally without the view code if this is unrelated.

Comment: I have added a example project to Github for you to look at:
https://github.com/GeneralMilhouse/SwiftData-Example/tree/main

Comment: I have the same issue right now, have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. A workaround I did was to create a struct that contained the variables I wanted to use, and then (in the next view) assign these to the Goal class. Not the most elegant solution but it works.